# Laravel: how to check an extra field while logging in, in addition to email and password?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want my users validate their email address before the can access to website.

I think there is no a prebuilt system, so I added an `enabled` boolean field, default `false`, to my users table.

How can I handle this?

I'm looking at source code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L74-L79

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

I'd like to override the 'attempt' method of guard ... but I've not idea of what is a 'guard' (I'll for for documentation, I promise) and where / how to override or extend or implement to check the enabled field

*EDIT*

I found this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users

I REALLY cannot understand where the call to this method come from... and how to populate the `$email` and `$password` vars......  Anyway I tried this, but I obtained NOTHING. No error, but user logged even if it has enabled set to false. Note that my 'username' field is litterally  'username'. I'm not using email field.

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'enabled' => true])) 
    {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect($this->redirectTo());
    }
}

public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a well- working solution

In my `LoginController.php` I override two function from the trait `AuthenticatesUsers;`.

Note that the 2nd override is just to override the message to the user.

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 * NOTE: this override DO NOT uses at all the trait version
 * See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return Auth::attempt(
        $this->credentials($request) + ["enabled" => true],
        $request->filled('remember')
    );
}

/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 * NOTE: this override DO NOT uses at all the trait version
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws ValidationException
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed_or_account_not_activated')],
    ]);
}
```

I add some explanations.

### About `attemptLogin`

Default implementation of the framework is

```
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
```

`attempt` accepts an array as first argument to be used for credentials, and a boolean as second argument, with the meaning of "remember user login'

The `credentials` function is implemented as

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

In my implementation, instead of passing username and password I pass

```
$this->credentials($request) + ["enabled" => true],
```

so I am passing 3 fields instead of only one; I pass

```
array [ 'username', 'password', 'enabled' ]
```

Internally the framework will do a lookup into db for a user with given username, password and enabled field values.

### About `sendFailedLoginResponse`

This override is only for showing a more precise error message to the user. Because user in this case can have right username and password, but he/she could be not enabled.

So I don't want a probably misleading error like "wrong user credentials', but a more contextualized "wrong user credentials or account not activated".

Default `sendFailedLoginResponse` implementation is

```
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
```

I simply asked Laravel to send a different string

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
    $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed_or_account_not_activated')],
]);
```

The strings to be translated must blaced into `resources/lang/<lang_code>/auth.php`

I added a string translation near the default

```
'failed' => 'Le credenziali inserite non corrispondono a nessun utente',
```

I added

```
'failed_or_account_not_activated' => "Le credenziali inserite non corrispondono a nessun utente oppure l'account non è stato ancora attivato",
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want my users validate their email address before the can access to
>   website.

- You can just use `Auth::attempt()` of laravel to login the user using the `email`. For more information, [visit this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users).

Note: If you also want to pass other field, you can do it like so:

`Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'enabled' => 1]);`